# How to generate correlation values in Spotfire using an R script

Tags: r, spotfire

I believe there is a way to generate correlation values in Spotfire without writing an R script however I would like to understand why the below code is not running in Spotfire. I also tried loading the stats and base libraries into Spotfire to no avail.

The script is below:

`output <- cor(input1, input2)`

The error message is below:

`TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error in library(pkg, character.only = TRUE) : there is no package called 'correlation''.`

Comment: try `stats::cor(input1,input2)`?

Comment: That works! Thank you Stedy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats most likely happening is that Tibco has a pre-installed package called correlation that masks the `cor()` function. Call it from the stats library with:

`stats::cor(input1,input2)`